# Макрос Excel ActiveCell

Tags: excel, vba

Как мне занести в переменную fStr значение из той ячейки, которая находится левее той, в которой у меня установлен курсор?

fStr = ActiveCell.Text 'Значение из ячейки слева от активной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поискал и нашел ответ: `fStr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Text`

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
Excel.Range er = excelApp.Selection;
fStr = er.Offset[0, -1].Text;
```